# onclick to whole activity

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a activity with a table layout and an Background 9.pic - 
the user just had to click anywhere to take some Action

I put the click listener to tablelayout but it seems not working

```
TableLayout TL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
    View view = TL;
    TL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            final Data p = new Data(); and so on ...
```

here is XML

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ort"
tools:context=".SchilderW_A"

    >


<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Feld1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="60sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow2"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Feld2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="60sp" />
</TableRow>


<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow3"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Feld3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="LE: " />
</TableRow>
```

I set before a onclick the tablelayout but it didn't work also

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Please post your xml layout

Comment: no - no exception - put XML

Comment: Have you tried onTouchListener?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should do try this

```
TableLayout TL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
TL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        final Data p = new Data(); and so on ...
```

Because every thing in  layout is the child of class view

Answer (score 0):

Put this in tablelayout

```
android:clickable="true"
```